# Translating "should" expressing future desirability

Tags: selección-de-palabras

## Español

Quiero expresar:

> You should come study with us tomorrow.

No con un sentido de probabilidad ("you are likely to") o de obligación ("...or else you won't pass the exam"), sino de deseo ("you would have fun and it would be a rewarding experience").

¿Podría *deberías* funcionar así?

> Deberías estudiar con nosotros mañana.

---

## English

I want to express:

> You should come study with us tomorrow.

Not in the sense of probability ("you are likely to") or obligation ("...or else you won't pass the exam"), but desirability ("you would have fun and it would be a rewarding experience").

Would *deberías* work here?

> Deberías estudiar con nosotros mañana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Español

Pienso que "Deberías estudiar con nosotros mañana" funciona a la perfección. Al igual que en inglés, el contexto nos dirá si la oración indica obligación o deseo.

---

## English

I think that "Deberías estudiar con nosotros mañana" works perfectly. Just like in English, the context will tell us if the sentence entails obligation or desirability.

Comment: "Deberías" implica una obligación es su forma primaria o sentido | "Deberías" imply an obligation in its primary form or sense

Comment: @user983248 Precisamente al usar el condicional toma el sentido de "recomendación", no de obligación.

Comment: @JoulSauron Te entiendo, aun asi creo que hay ejemplos mas simples que deben de ser tomados en cuenta antes de utilizar ejemplos mas complejos donde el contexto y el orden de las palabras pueden cambiar el significado de la frase. - Uno no comienza con 9 = x . 1/3x uno comienza con 1 + 1 :)

Comment: "Deberias ir" es obligación, "Deberias de ir" es deseo. Y confundirlos es una falta gramatical

Comment: "Deberias ir" IS WRONG. You must say "Deberias de ir" for a wish.

Comment: @Leandro. It's not wrong and there's no need to yell. "No obstante, con este sentido, la lengua culta admite también el uso sin preposición". http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=deber. Shame on you if you are a Spanish teacher as you said in your answer.

Comment: La preposicion marca un giro de semantica sobre la proposicion del giro verbal en infinitivo porque es una evolucion de la atraccion del relativo (que en este caso se encuentra en una elipsis) y se hereda del latin. La RAE, a proposito, no es fuente gramatical. En cualquier obra de gramatica de primaria se puede encontrar el caso.

Comment: @Leandro Creo que Juan Pablo tiene razón, pero no porque lo diga la Academia, sino porque el uso ha borrado esa distinción que tú señalas (y que sigue figurando en las obras de gramática antiguas o no puestas al día).

Answer (score -1):

### Español

Creo que si utilizas "deberías" estas implicando un "deber" u obligación. Si lo que quieres es dar a entender es opcional (si la otra persona desea) creo que puedes utilizar "If you wish"

- You should come study with us tomorrow, if you wish.
- If you wish, you should come study with us tomorrow.

Para hacerlo mas opcional puedes remover "should" y utilizar "can" en su lugar.

- You can come study with us tomorrow, if you wish.
- If you wish, you can come study with us tomorrow.

### English

If you use "deberías" you are implying a duty or obligation. If what you are trying to express is optional (if the other person feels like) I think you can use "if you whish"

To make it more optional you can remove "should" and use "can" instead.

### Both / Ambos

Other variable to "if you wish"
Otras variaciones de "if you wish"

- Si lo deseas -> If you wish
- Si quieres -> If you want
- si te parece -> If you feel like
- si te gusta -> If you like

Recuerda que puedes agregar "ti / tu" para hacer la frase mas formal.

Remember you can add "ti / tu" to make the phrase more formal.

Comment: -1 Te desviaste de la pregunta. Tu respuesta se centro mas en decirle como pedirlo en ingles, y el obviamente lo que deseaba era saberlo en español.

Answer (score -2):

**Español:**

Es simple, para expresar deseo se utiliza el modo subjuntivo:

> Debieres estudiar con nosotros mañana.

Sin embargo casi ningún hispano hablante lo entiende, porque hablamos muy mal.

Lo mejor sería utilizar un condicional con una expresión de deseo:

> Ojalá estudiaras con nosotros mañana.

Incluso peor, pocos hablantes de español hablamos con futuro. En jerga vulgar **deberías de** decir:

> ```
> Ojalá pudieras estudiar con nosotros mañana.
> ```

"Deberias ir" es obligación, "Deberias de ir" es deseo. Y confundirlos es una falta gramatical

**English:**

It's sample, to express a wish you must use the subjuntivo mode:

> Debieres estudiar con nosotros mañana.

But we speak very bad spanish, so any native will understand you. A better approach is use a conditional with a desire expression:

> Ojalá estudiaras con nosotros mañana.

(Ojalá means "I wish", from "Oh Alá", from Arabic invassion on Spain.

Even worst, a very little natives speak with future. In a "populum vox", you **should** say:

> ```
> Ojalá pudieras estudiar con nosotros mañana.
> ```

"Deberias ir" is an obligation, "Deberias de ir" is a wish. Confuse them and you will speak bad.

PD: I'm spanish teacher.

Comment: "Debieres estudiar con nosotros mañana" no es precisamente un ejemplo de buen uso del lenguaje. El futuro del subjuntivo es de por sí un arcaísmo que se mantiene sólo en algunos ámbitos específicos. Aun así, dudo que en algún momento se haya usado como en la frase anterior. Dos opciones correctas serían "deberías" (que va con tilde) o "debieras", ambas aceptadas por razones históricas. "Deber de" más infinitivo significa suposición o conjetura y "Deber" más infinitivo significa tanto suposición como obligación en el uso corriente; además está aceptado por la RAE.

Comment: La preposicion marca un giro de semantica sobre la proposicion del giro verbal en infinitivo porque es una evolucion de la atraccion del relativo (que en este caso se encuentra en una elipsis) y se hereda del latin. La RAE, a proposito, no es fuente gramatical. En cualquier obra de gramatica de primaria se puede encontrar el caso.